# Kendo UI Uploader Async Cross Site Scripting Issue with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have attempted to use the Kendo UI Uploader in async mode in an ASP.NET environment, using very similar code to the demo's on there site and am getting what appears to be a JQuery cross site scripting error on both IE8 and Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m

The following is the code being used:

index.chtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/kendostyles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/kendostyles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="scripts/kendojs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/kendojs/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<div style="width:45%">
    <div style="width:45%">
        <div class="demo-section">
            <input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#files").kendoUpload({
                async: {
                    saveUrl: "save",
                    removeUrl: "remove",
                    autoUpload: true
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have extremely simple upload code that is not even being hit, but i will provide it for completeness:

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            // Some browsers send file names with full path.
            // We are only interested in the file name.
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), fileName);
            // The files are not actually saved in this demo
            // file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
        }
    }

    // Return an empty string to signify success
    return View();
}
```

Now upon selecting a file to be uploaded i receive the following javascript pop up message:

```
Error! Upload failed.Unexpected server response - see console.
```

Upon viewing the console i get this:

```
Server response: Error trying to get server response: SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:21739" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.
```

in an attempt to resolve the issue after searching around for like issues i have tried bypassing the issue with changing the global.asax file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```

But that had no effect.

What is the way to get the Async Kendo File Upload working when presented with this sort of error, i have been unable to find anyone suffering from the same situation?

Comment: Is CORS working on the server? I'm guessing not.

Comment: Never tried this but see if http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/ helps you out. Feel free to answer yourself if it does or if you found another solution.

Comment: Well since its on the inbuilt Visual Studio cut down version of IIS (casini) i can see this being a problem, also i will need to support IE before 10 and the article said thats a no go, so may have to scrap this idea all together

Comment: CORS is supported in IE8, but the API used to implement it is Microsoft's own and it may have more restrictions than what's offered by later versions of IE or other browsers.

Comment: Ooops, I take that back.  *What we call CORS* may or may not explicitly be supported, but cross domain support does exist in IE8. Oye.

Comment: Thanks for the comments JayC, as mentioned below once i fixed the controller it worked, but threw the same error when uploading large files, which is why i was testing these, so i think i shall move on to the next idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) chrome is explicit about XSS problems. Unless chrome console says cross site scripting error, then I don't think that's your issue.

2) Add yourself a call back for when it errors out.

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: "save",
                removeUrl: "remove",
                autoUpload: true
            },
            error: onError
        });

function onError(e){
alert("Failed to upload " + e.files.length + " files " + e.XMLHttpRequest.status + " " + e.XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
}
```

This will give you the response from the server.

3) Not sure if you are using Asp.net MVC or Web Api controllers (looks like ASP.Net MVC), but (maybe I'm wrong) it seems your save property needs the controller or route details.

```
          $("#files").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: "MyControllerName/save", (or api/controller) ( or @Url.Action("Save", "ControllerName")
                removeUrl: "remove",
                autoUpload: true
            }
        });
```

4) returning KendoUI upload isn't going to like the return type `ActionResult` It requires a `JsonResult` return type. **correction : Not 100% sure on this. Just be careful of how the return data is structured. If it's a string with well-formed HTML, the control will bark**

Comment: Thanks TSmith, you are very correct in regards to the ASP.Net MVC and also the controller not being set properly, i have fixed that (can't believe i missed it, in saying that this is about the 5th way i have tried to test large file uploading today and a 14 hour day may be getting to me)

Comment: I have been unable to find any documentation say that the return needs to be a jsonresult all the examples are action results

Comment: OK the new issue appears to be the return View(); in the the controller, return Content(""); lets it work, still having a problem with large files (600 meg just fails instantly) but that wasn't the point of this post, thanks for the help

Comment: Cool. Yah, I may have misspoke on the return type. But in my scenario I was attaching the upload to the KendoUI editor and needed to return the file contents (text data) back to the uploader to update the editor. At first I tried returning a PartialViewResult which caused the uploader to freak. So I then wrapped the data in a JsonResult and updated the editor via the DOM api. So that's where I was coming from with that...

Comment: Yeap, makes sense :) i have utilized the editor before, back to the search for a reliable cross browsers large file upload component